# How to get text from a window using HIServices/Carbon Framework?

Tags: macos, accessibility, macos-carbon

I am creating a MAC app which is aimed for people with disabilities.  I intend the application to read out the text in documents or webpages opened in different applications/browsers.

For inspecting the hierarchy of UI Elements in different apps, I am using the Accessibility Inspector Utility provided by Apple. I have found that if my AXUIElement is a window (for example, Firefox) or a view (for example, Word), I am unable to retrieve the text.

I am also using the following code in an app for retrieving text:

```
 NSString *textContents = [UIElementUtilities descriptionForUIElement:newElement attribute:(NSString *)kAXValueAttribute beingVerbose:NO];
```

But I am unable to get text.

Comment: Can I ask why? It seems like you are trying to recreate VoiceOver. Are you wanting to develop a simplier audio output program?

Comment: I am learning Mac development and it's an assignment which has been given to me. :)

Comment: I can think of two possibilities; the examples you cited either aren't using native controls at all (which is likely in Firefox) or are using Carbon instead of Cocoa (which is likely in Microsoft Word).  Standard Cocoa controls are generally fully-accessible; Carbon controls are somewhat accessible but not as exposed as Cocoa is.  It is *possible* for 3rd parties to make their custom views accessible but since this is "extra work" they aren't necessarily going to bother.